# Threejs FPS with text objects

Tags: animation, text, three.js, frame-rate

I'm working on a ThreeJS project where there is a text tunnel, created by generating text objects with TextGeometry, and moving them along the z axis continuously. The objects are generated dynamically. I use 30 at a time with a circular buffer.

For some reason, I get a good FPS (around 60 or more), but it varies a lot. There are drops in FPS every 5-10 seconds or so. I've tested the code in several conditions (i.e. not using other elements like other objects, video capture, cam movement, etc.) and I am pretty sure the moving text objects are the cause of drop in FPS.

Ideas?

ThreeJS update function:

```
function update()
{   
bookidx = bookidx % book.length;

// FLOATING TEXT
if (stepsFloating++ % floatingWordsRate == 0 && makeFloatingWords){
    addFloatingText(book[bookidx], scene);
}
else{
    floatingWords.move();
}

// TUNNEL TEXT
// move sentences forward
for (t in tunnelWords.tokens){
    tunnelWords.tokens[t][1].position.z += 120;
}

// get another sentence
if (tunnelWords.tokens[0][1].position.z > -2000){
    addTunnelText(book[bookidx++], scene);  
}

// KEYBOARD
keyboardUpdate();

// CONTROLS AND STATS
controls.update();
stats.update();
}
```

This creates the object (I intentionally use a high bevel thickness for the effect, decreasing it or not using it at all did not make a difference:

```
function makeTextMeshForTunnel(word){
var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( word , 
{
    size: 22, height: 1, curveSegments: 1,
    font: "helvetiker", weight: "normal", style: "normal",
    bevelThickness: 900, bevelSize: 2, bevelEnabled: true,
    material: 1, extrudeMaterial: 0
});

// font: helvetiker, gentilis, droid sans, droid serif, optimer
// weight: normal, bold

var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeom, tunnel_textMaterial );
textGeom.computeBoundingBox();
var textWidth = textGeom.boundingBox.max.x - textGeom.boundingBox.min.x;

textMesh.position.set( -0.5 * textWidth, 0, -3000 );
textMesh.rotation.x = TUNNEL_TEXT_X_ROTATION;
return textMesh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps, seems textGeometry is more costly than other geometries, this helps to understand the problem with suggested solutions:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1825